# Responsive leave out Divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

On a Timeline i would like to Display the hours of a Day: **JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/9532otkm/2/ (simplified).

```
<div class="day">
<div class="hour">1</div>
<div class="hour">2</div>
<div class="hour">3</div>
<div class="hour">4</div>
...
<div class="hour">22</div>
<div class="hour">23</div>
<div class="hour">24</div>
</div>

.day{
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    width: 800px;

}
.hour{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

when the outside div becomes smaller there will be no more room to display all the hours.

Is it possible with responsive css / jquery to rescale in a manner that i left out some divs.

for example: 
first all the hours, if not enough room, then only hours 3, 9, 15 & 21...

Comment: 3, 9, 15 and 21 why? What's the pattern to hide some fields?

Comment: i wasnt clear, i meant the otherway round, only Display 3,9, 15 & 21 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @media query for this

```css
.day{
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hour{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {  /* adjust the 700px value for your needs */

  /* specific items ver. 2 */
  .hour
  {display: none}
  
  .hour:nth-of-type(3),
  .hour:nth-of-type(9),
  .hour:nth-of-type(15),
  .hour:nth-of-type(21)
  {display: inline-block}

  /* specific items
  .hour:nth-of-type(3),
  .hour:nth-of-type(9),
  .hour:nth-of-type(15),
  .hour:nth-of-type(21)
  {display: none}
  */

  /* odd or even
  .hour:nth-of-type(even)
  {display: none}
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="day">
  <div class="hour">1</div>
  <div class="hour">2</div>
  <div class="hour">3</div>
  <div class="hour">4</div>
  <div class="hour">5</div>
  <div class="hour">6</div>
  <div class="hour">7</div>
  <div class="hour">8</div>
  <div class="hour">9</div>
  <div class="hour">10</div>
  <div class="hour">11</div>
  <div class="hour">12</div>
  <div class="hour">13</div>
  <div class="hour">14</div>
  <div class="hour">15</div>
  <div class="hour">16</div>
  <div class="hour">17</div>
  <div class="hour">18</div>
  <div class="hour">19</div>
  <div class="hour">20</div>
  <div class="hour">21</div>
  <div class="hour">22</div>
  <div class="hour">23</div>
  <div class="hour">24</div>
</div>
```

*Updated based on comment*

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  document.querySelector('.day').style.width = e.target.value + 'px';
  if (e.target.value < 484) {
    document.querySelector('.day').classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.day').classList.remove('hide');
  }
})
```

```css
.day{
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  width: 484px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hour{
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.day.hide .hour{
  display: none
} 
.day.hide .hour:nth-of-type(3),
.day.hide .hour:nth-of-type(9),
.day.hide .hour:nth-of-type(15),
.day.hide .hour:nth-of-type(21){
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="day">
  <div class="hour">1</div>
  <div class="hour">2</div>
  <div class="hour">3</div>
  <div class="hour">4</div>
  <div class="hour">5</div>
  <div class="hour">6</div>
  <div class="hour">7</div>
  <div class="hour">8</div>
  <div class="hour">9</div>
  <div class="hour">10</div>
  <div class="hour">11</div>
  <div class="hour">12</div>
  <div class="hour">13</div>
  <div class="hour">14</div>
  <div class="hour">15</div>
  <div class="hour">16</div>
  <div class="hour">17</div>
  <div class="hour">18</div>
  <div class="hour">19</div>
  <div class="hour">20</div>
  <div class="hour">21</div>
  <div class="hour">22</div>
  <div class="hour">23</div>
  <div class="hour">24</div>
</div>
<input type="range" name="points" min="100" max="968">
```

Comment: Thank you!

I understand the max-width stands for Screen-width.

Is it possible to link to the "day"-Dav instead?

Comment: @Paul If you by `screen` mean `viewport` (browser window), yes, else no, not the monitor's screen.

Comment: @Paul Updated my answer

Comment: the 700px is the viewport, right?, but i can Change the day-div with a slider, and _then:_ i want the numbers to disappear, not when changing the browser-window :) (hope this makes clear what im up to :))

Comment: @Paul that makes things trickier. Could you update your question with a more complete picture of your code (javascript used for the slider, etc)

Comment: @Paul Added a 2:nd sample showing how a "slider" can be used

Comment: @LGSon, you're the best! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A custom solution is to add classes to the hours like so

```
<div class="hour small">6</div>480px
```

Ansd then add an extra css styling when screen is less then 480px to hide the element with this class name

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .small {
      display : none;
    }
}
```

See updated fiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/9532otkm/5/

Comment: Thank you, see my comment on LGSon' solution :)

Comment: @Paul : Do you want a slider that numbers disapear or? and you want a fixed width for the day div? or?